# Inject variable in EJS for this specific case

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am running this code in EJS

```
 <%   for (var i=1; i <= event[0].eventWinners; i++ ) { %>
  <td>
    <%= event[0].winner+i.name %>
  </td>
<% } %>
```

Actually, I want it to render if there are 4 winners in the loop.

```
<%= event[0].winner1.name %>
<%= event[0].winner2.name %>
<%= event[0].winner3.name %>
<%= event[0].winner4.name %>
```

But I get NaN as result. Any advice?

Adding data sample here

```
[
eventWinners : 5,
winner1 :{name: "abc"},
winner2 :{name: "abc2"},
winner3 :{name: "abc3"},
winner4 :{name: "abc3"},
winner4 :{name: "abc4"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summing the `winner` with the `name`, you have to create the dynamic field scanning:

```
<%   for (var i=1; i <= event[0].eventWinners; i++ ) { %>
  <td>
    <% Object.keys(event[0]).filter(c => c.startsWith("winner")).forEach(c => { %>
       <%= event[0][c].name %>
    <% }) %>
  </td>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you. Something is wrong here as I am getting blank data now.

Comment: Try now. It was accessing it the wrong way.

Comment: unfortunately the same thing.

Comment: I have added the sample data that I am getting in event[0]